# message gets delay in quickblox chat api

Tags: ios, quickblox

when sender send a message using quickblox chat api it will take upto 6sec or more to delivered. So is it possible to optimise the time it will take for acknowledgment.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

QuickBlox has a server shared between all shared users. This affects chat requests.

With dedicated environment (enterprise) you will see improvement in all aspects of QuickBlox modules.

https://quickblox.com/enterprise/